# Calendar binding SelectedDate and DisplayDate: gray dates

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, calendar

**The original use case:**

This is a possible use case I'm trying to solve:

1. The user opens the page with my calendar set to the now date
2. User selects a date a few months back
3. User refreshes the page, causing the selected date in the VM to be reset to the now date

*Expected:* The calendar displays the now date

*Actual:* (with binding only on SelectedDate) The calendar only moves its selected date, but keeps showing the previously selected month

**My solution:**

In an MVVM scenario I am showing a `Calendar` control whose SelectedDate has a binding to a `SelectedDate` property in my ViewModel. The property in my VM triggers it's `PropertyChanged` event when set.

The selected date in my VM can also be set from other parts in my code, so I want my calendar to always show the selected date (for example when another month is set as the selected date, I want my calendar to switch to that month). To get this behavior I also bound the `DisplayDate` property of my calendar to my SelectedDate property, and this gives me the expected behavior, except when I click on the gray dates of the previous or next month.

This is my Calendar in XAML:

```xml
<Calendar SelectedDate="{Binding Path=SelectedDate}" DisplayDate="{Binding Path=SelectedDate}" />
```

This the `SelectedDate` property in my ViewModel (implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`)

```cpp
    public DateTime SelectedDate
    {
        get 
        { 
            return selectedDate; 
        }
        set 
        { 
            selectedDate = value;
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedDate"));
        }
    }
```

**The problem with the solution:**

Apparently clicking on a gray date causes the `SelectedDate` to be set on mouse down and again on mouse up, which causes a selection of a date two months away.

Is there a better way to implement this kind of behavior? Or can I fix the DisplayDate problem (without too much hacking, meaning no/as little code as possible in code behind)?

All I really want is a `SelecteDate` property which also has the behavior of the `DisplayDate` property :)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you saying that you want the Calendar to always show the month (when opened) of the SelectedDate?

Comment: Yes I want the calendar to always show the Date in the SelectedDate property of my view model. This date can also change from within the view model, so I want the calendar to always jump to the selected date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I have settled on fixing it now is in my code behind, on the loaded event of the calendar:

```
private void CalendarLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.ViewStartCalendar.SelectedDate.HasValue)
    {
        this.ViewStartCalendar.DisplayDate = this.ViewStartCalendar.SelectedDate.Value;
    }
}
```

I would have rather done it in XAML or in my viewmodel, but I can live with this solution.

Comment: Thx, if there is clean MVVM way to resolve this issue i wolud be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 5):

I've just had this problem arise and stumbled upon this answer which although it worked I deconstructing further and found the solution is extremely simple.  Simply bind to the `DisplayDate` as `Mode=OneTime`. Nothing else is needed.

```
DisplayDate="{Binding SelectedDate, Mode=OneTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```